# Double subquery no see a column

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I need to build a query, but I can not assign a column in a subquery within another subquery.

For example:

When i have

```
SELECT 
    q,w,e,r,t,y, -- some values of first table
    (SELECT data FROM OTHER WHERE t.q = some) -- fisrt subquery
FROM TABLE t
where ....
```

Works beacuse fisrt subquery can read `t.q`

But when i tried use

```
SELECT 
    q,w,e,r,t,y --
    ( -- first wub query
    SELECT 
        a * b + c 
    FROM ( --second subquery
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM ANOTHER 
        WHERE t.q = some )  
    )
FROM TABLE t
where ....
```

I get `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't.q' in 'where clause'`

How I can use my field to the subquery?

Comment: This looks like it should be solved with a join - please post your Schema!

Comment: I tried implement a join, but when t.q is not specified in the second subquery the second subquery throws bad results, therefore the results of the join are wrong :(